# Cannot add package to local npm cache

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-cache

If I try to add my local project to the npm cache, nothing seems to get added to the .npm dir:

```
"$(npm get cache)" => "$HOME/.npm"
```

given the npm cache location, we do:

```
rm -rf "$HOME/.npm"
mkdir "$HOME/.npm"
npm cache add "$my_npm_project_root"
```

the command succeeds, but nothing gets added to the "$HOME/.npm" dir.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Why isn't the cache being updated?

Comment: I am on  `npm version: 5.6.0`, ftr

Comment: Same issue after updating to version `6.0.1`

Comment: So you want to add your project xyz to your npm cache AS A PACKAGE, so you can use it from other projects on your computer without publishing xyz to npm repository?